# ReferenceError: session is not defined with ('connect-mongo')(session),

Tags: node.js, session, express

I'm trying to add [connect-mongo](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo) in order to save sessions when nodeJS restarts.

Per the documentation I added: 
`MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),`

and in my `require('express-session')` I added

```
store: new MongoStore({
    url: mongooseDB,
    touchAfter: 24 * 3600
})
```

and commented out `app.use(passport.session());`

I'm getting an error: ReferenceError: session is not defined which is pointed to `MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),`

I've added my app.js file for reference. How can I fix this?

```js
'use strict';
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
    passport = require('passport'),
    flash = require('connect-flash'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    User = require('./models/user'),
    faker = require('faker'),
    path = require('path');

const indexRoute = require('./routes/index'),
    usersRoute = require('./routes/users'),
    giftsRoute = require('./routes/gifts.js'),
    searchRoute = require('./routes/search');

const mongooseDB = 'mongodb://localhost/giftcashing';

mongoose.connect(mongooseDB);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(flash());

app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'anything',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: mongooseDB,
        touchAfter: 24 * 3600
    })
}));

// PASSPORT CONFIGURATION
app.use(passport.initialize());
// app.use(passport.session());

// use static authenticate method of model in LocalStrategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

// use static serialize and deserialize of model for passport session support
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    next();
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   var err = new Error('Not Found');
//   err.status = 404;
//   next(err);
// });

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

app.use('/', indexRoute);
app.use('/users', usersRoute);
app.use('/gifts', giftsRoute);
app.use('/search', searchRoute);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable `session` is not initialized when you are calling
`MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)`.

Add `session = require('express-session')` before initializing `MongoStore`.

Comment: You are awesome :) That worked :) I also had to uncomment app.use(passport.session()); because for some reason it wasn't letting me log in but i worked it out. :) You're awesome.